# Getting the selected value from a DropDownListFor using a ViewBag list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble getting the data from a DropDownListFor using a ViewBag list with my model. Here is my Controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult JoinTeam()
{
    var TeamList = _db.TeamModels.ToList();
    SelectList list = new SelectList(TeamList, "Id", "TeamName");
    ViewBag.TeamList = list;

    return View();
}
```

And the Razor view form looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("JoinTeam", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DisplayName, new { @class = "form-control form-control-lg", placeholder = "Enter your Battle Net ID" })
    <br/>

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TeamModel, (SelectList)ViewBag.TeamList, "- Select a Team to Join -", new { @class= "form-control form-control-lg" })
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%;text-align:center;">Submit</button>
}
```

The TextBoxFor helper is returning the data correctly, but whatever option I have selected in the drop down does not get passed into my post method. Does anyone have any ideas?

The post action does work as it's getting the data from the model for the TextBoxFor help, but here's what it looks like:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> JoinTeam(GuardianModel model)
    {            

        try
        {
            string BNETId = model.DisplayName.Replace("#", "%23");
            long memberId = 0;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Bungie.Responses.SearchPlayersResponse member = await service.SearchPlayers(MembershipType.Blizzard, BNETId);
                memberId = member[0].MembershipId;
            }
            using (var context = new CoCodbEntities1())
            {
                var g = new GuardianModel
                {
                    MembershipId = memberId.ToString(),
                    DisplayName = BNETId,
                    MembershipType = 4,
                    TeamID = model.TeamModel.Id
                };
                TempData["UserMessage"] = ViewBag.TeamList.Id;
                return RedirectToAction("Success");
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        return View();
    }
```

[These are the values getting passed into the Post action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMEGn.jpg)

Comment: What does your post action look like? What is the contents of your post request (the browser's debugger will show you)?

Comment: I updated my original question with the post action. Thanks.

Comment: With the code you shared, model binder should be able to map the selected option value to the `TeamModel` property of your `GuardianModel` parameter of your http post action method. Are you 100% sure it is not populated ? (Can you put a breakpoint in the code and inspect the value ?)

Comment: I updated the question with a snip of the values getting passed to the post action.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot you shared, it looks like `TeamModel` property is the virtual navigational property of type `TeamModel`.  You should not bother about loading that. All you need to worry about loading the forign key property value (usually a simple type like an `int` or so.

Your SELECT element name should be `TeamID`. When the form is submitted, it will map the selected option value to the `TeamID` property value of your model which is the foreign key property.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TeamID, (SelectList)ViewBag.TeamList,
           "- Select a Team to Join -", new { @class= "form-control form-control-lg" })
```

While this might fix the issue, It is a good idea to use a view model instead of using your entity class.

Comment: You should consider using a view model.

Comment: Instead of using ViewBag? Is there a reason why I should?

Comment: Yes. ViewBag is dynamic. So if you make a typo, it won't be caught in compile time. Also you should not make your view layer strongly coupled to your ORM entities.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issues I was having. All I needed to get passed into the post action was the Id of the TeamModel. So I changed this line:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TeamModel.Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.TeamList, "- Select a Team to Join -", new { @class= "form-control form-control-lg" })
```

I just added the Id and it seemed to work.